# Why does libc++ not support such a basic atomic operation?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, atomic, libc++

```
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic_size_t a{ 3 };
    std::atomic_fetch_sub(&a, 1); // vc++ ok, but clang++ failed.
}
```

The code above is ok by *vc++*, but failed by *clang++ 8.0* with:

`clang++ -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp`

```
error: no matching function for call to 'atomic_fetch_sub'
    std::atomic_fetch_sub(&a, 1);
```

**Why does libc++ not support such a basic atomic operation?**

Comment: it is strange. gcc just works fine. clang work just fine for other data types such as `std::atomic_int` too. I don't know why this one is not implemented correctly in templates. bug maybe?

Comment: What platform are you working on? What version of LLVM/Clang are you using? For Clang 8.0 on Fedora 30, I get a compile error due to `-stdlib=libc++`. Once the option is removed it compiles OK.

Comment: If you change your code to `std::atomic_fetch_sub(&a, 1UL);` then it works.

Comment: @jww same as yours.

Comment: The code fails for me in both g++ 8.3 and clang++ 8.0.0 (std=c++17 mode, no library selection switch) with the same error. As a workaround you can use `a.fetch_sub(1);`

Comment: @MarshallClow Why would 1UL be working, from what I read the second argument is deduced from the atomic (difference_type). It doesn't look like the right size (as that should be 1ULL), so is it because it is unsigned?

Comment: I think it's a library bug (on godbolt it occurs in g++ 8 but not g++ 9), something to do with how they implement `std::atomic` as derived from `__atomic_base` but they overload `atomic_fetch_sub` in a different way for both the base and derived classes , and overload resolution fails as a result. Maybe a LLVM bug report would be in order

Comment: The answer is probably that libc++ implements an older version of the `<atomic>` specification, and we haven't updated it yet.  @M.M's comment about gcc8 vs. gcc9 suggests that libstdc++ updated their implementation then.